# Postgress.app: Searching through history

Tags: shell, postgresql, psql

Say I type multiple commands:

```
select something from table
select foo from bar
...
```

How can I search through my command history as I type a command/query?

E.g. if I start typing:

```
select some
```

and then I press `C-r`, can I have psql search and autocomplete my command  with entries that **start with** `select some`? (i.e. *select foo from bar* would be skipped)

Note that I am asking for searches that fix the characters typed so far.

Comment: `psql` already implements reverse-search in history with `C-r`, provided it's compiled with libreadline or equivalent.

Comment: @user815423426 Off topic, according to the link. Kinda fair, but I wouldn't worry.